# Search for missing data starting with certain text

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula

Hello I need to compare two columns and output all missing data into a third column.

The problem is that I need to also filter the first column for only certain cells that start with two letters

This is what put together and was expecting to work but I am not sure whether I am using incorrect formulas or the identificator for the starting text is not working..

```
=ArrayFormula(FILTER(D3:D;ISERROR(MATCH(REGEXMATCH(D3:D;"MY.");A2:A;0))))
```

- Column "D" contains all data to be filtered

  - it contains cells starting with "MY", "NY", and "FY"
- Column "A" contains all data to be compared to

  - this one may be missing some cells "MY...." and that is what I need this formula for

Comment: So do you want col D with results that do not start with  `MY`, `NY`,`FY`? Please share a test sheet with expected results

Comment: Hello, here is a link https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-vTqf1Bayo256nwEgF85-leH4gburk1Zgga-TxOEndY

Comment: Please change permissions to the sheet to `Anyone with the link can access` and **just** `Protect` the sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a query formula instead:

```
=QUERY(A1:D14 ;"SELECT D WHERE D like 'MY%' and not A like 'MY%'";1)
```

Please read more about [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en-GB)

***Note that*** if you use a different `Locale` in your sheet you would have to change `;` to `,` for the formula to work.

[image: query for missing data]